# Send HTML checkbox values to flask without using form

Tags: python, jquery, json, ajax, flask

Suppose, I have a simple HTML checkbox.
When the HTML page is loaded through flask initially, this checkbox displays boolean values from a postgres database. It cannot be included in an HTML form, nor I can use submit button.
Now, if I tick/untick this checkbox, I want to send the value associated with this checkbox to flask and ultimately to db.
Can I do it with ninja or do I need ajax call for it?? I tried with ajax, but :(

I am a newbie to ajax,json,flask.

I tried searching other questions, but most of them I found were with HTML form or with php.
Sorry for my lack of knowledge, if I miss something.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="statustick" name="statustick" value="{{ testvariable }}" {% if testvariable==True %}checked{% endif %}>


<script>
$("#statustick").change( function(){
   if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ url_for('logging') }}",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify("#check".val()),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    });

   }else{
        alert("unchecked");
   }
});
```

Comment: are there are more checkbox ? or only one ? Also `"#check".val()` should be `$(this).val()`

Comment: Can you post the code behind `"{{ url_for('logging') }}"` in flask ? Does your api call goes through ? Use a debugger to see if your request goes correctly through your network (F12 on Chrome and Firefox), or if you get an error. Please provide more details so we can help you.

Comment: Apologies for replying so late.Thanks to both of you @Swati for your comment. I sorted it out using ajax call. I didnt include the checkbox in the form and kept it out of the form. Made a onchange function and wrote a js script for the onchange function, making a ajax call. It worked.